# música não toca

Tags: python, pygame

Estou com o seguinte código em python

```
#*-coding:utf-8;-*
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('ex1.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

No caso, ele deveria tocar uma música ao ser rodado no pycharm, porém, ele executa a função, espera alguns segundos e simplesmente encerra o programa, sem retornar nenhum erro, como posso corrigir isso?

Ao usar desta forma

```
#*-coding:utf-8;-*
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('ex1.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
import time
time.sleep(360)
```

O código rodou normalmente, mas creio que não seja a melhor forma de fazer isso com python/pygame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('ex1.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
x = input('Digite algo para parar...')
```

Comment: ainda não me parece uma boa alternativa

Comment: funcionou o que eu propus?

Comment: funciona, mas isso faz com que eu não consiga executar nada mais junto à música, e também, não acho que seja um bom método, por isso não dei como resposta

Answer (score 3):

A questão é que a chamada `pygame.event.wait()` em quase todos os casos vai retornar imediatamente: ela retorna *qualquer* evento do Pygame - incluindo movimentação do mouse, etc...

Se você quer executar código em paraleleo com a música tocando, simplesmente *escreva esse código*  a chamada ao pygame.mixer.music.play() inicia a música de forma assíncrona, em paralelo ao seu código Python.

Se voce usar time.sleep, o seu código Python não faz nada e  a música fic atocando. A chamada ao `event.wait()` retorna, e o programa é encerrado - por isso a diferença entre o seu código. 
Se você tiver um laço principal da sua aplicação, esperando eventos do teclado, fazendo coisas, etc...isso vai funcionar enquanto a música toca.

(dica em paralelo: rodar o programa por dentro do pycharm é apenas uma facilidade do pycharm enquanto se está desenvolvendo - é importante entender que o seu programa existe e pode ser chamado direto pelo sistema operacional.  Os programas em Python não rodam "dentro do pycharm". )

Comment: não entendi a questão do método assíncrono, ainda sou iniciante no python e não sei utilizar este método

Answer (score 2):

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('mu.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
x = input('Digite algo para parar a musica...')
```

Encurtando o código

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('mu.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
x = input('Digite algo para parar a musica...')
```

Em vez colocar o código da maneira que você colocou coloque assim e funcionará... como o Victor Antonio disse, a chamada ao `event.wait()` retorna e o programa é encerrado...

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro metodo não está funcionando pois deveria ser `pygame.mixer.init()` ao invés de `pygame.init()`

Comment: Eu estive lendo a documentação do [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init) e vi que a lógica tem fundamento mas a função sugerida é outra. Está escrito "Algumas plataformas exigem que o módulo `pygame.mixer`,  seja inicializado após a inicialização dos módulos de exibição. No nível superior `pygame.init()` cuida disso automaticamente, mas não pode passar nenhum argumento para o init do mixer. Para resolver isso, o mixer possui uma função `pygame.mixer.pre_init()`para definir os padrões adequados antes que o init de nível superior seja usado."

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é utilizar um laço de repetição junto ao controle se o ***mixer.music*** está ocupado (método *get_busy*).

No exemplo eu estou repetindo a música até que a variável *i* seja maior que *5*.

```
from pygame import mixer
import time

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('ex1.mp3')
mixer.music.play(-1)
i = 0
while (mixer.music.get_busy()):
  # Executa o que você quiser executar, no exemplo estou executando somente um sleep e um print
  # Fiz uma condição para quando o i > 5 parar de tocar a música e parar a execução por consequência
  time.sleep(1)
  if i > 5:
    mixer.music.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema utilizando `pygame` e consegui corrigi-lo criando uma janela através de `pygame.display.set_mode`. Para mim pelo menos, o `mixer` só funcionou após isso. Tente esse código:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
w_geometry = (300,300)
pygame.display.set_mode(w_geometry)
pygame.mixer.music.load('ex1.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Dica: É muito legal também que você utilize `pygame.mixer.init` passando o tamanho do `buffer` para que não haja um delay. Quando menor o tamanho do buffer, menos será o atraso. Exemplo:

```
import pygame
pygame.init.mixer(buffer=128)
pygame.init()
w_geometry = (300,300)
pygame.display.set_mode(w_geometry)
pygame.mixer.music.load('ex1.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: Ficaria melhor como comentário.

Comment: Ok, vejam se agora ficou melhor. Eu coloquei como resposta e não como comentário pois quando eu comecei aqui no StackOverFlow apareceu uma mensagem dizendo que toda e qualquer resposta deveria ser colocada como resposta. Já perguntas e outros deveriam ser colocados em comentário.